# Making arduino only write when signaled (serial)

Tags: serial-port, arduino, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to communicate between a Raspberry Pi and Arduino with USB serial, but I only want the Arduino to write when the RPI sends a signal.

My arduino code is as follows:

```
int sensorPin = A0;  
int sensorValue = 0;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    Serial.read();
    Serial.println(sensorValue,DEC);
    Serial.flush();
  }    
}
```

Once i do one call from the RPI of:

```
serial.write('hey')
```

The arduino writes repeatedly. I thought Serial.available would return 0 most of the time because the buffer is cleared by the read, but it seems like it never gets cleared. I thought flush() might do it but it doesn't really have any effect.

Comment: Off topic. This looks fun, what are you eventually trying to make? - arduino enthusiast.

Answer (score 3):

That's odd.. `Serial.read()` should remove the bytes from the buffer after reading them.

**Note:** Keep in mind that `Serial.read()` only reads one byte at a time, this could be your issue since you're sending `'hey'` from the Raspberry Pi it'll take 3 iterations of the loop the completely empty the buffer.

If this is not the issue you could try the [`serialEvent()`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SerialEvent) function wich is called each time something arrives trough serial.

Your code would be like this:

```
int sensorPin = A0;  
int sensorValue = 0;

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
     //Any other logic here   
}

void serialEvent() {
    sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
    Serial.read();
    Serial.println(sensorValue,DEC);
}
```

By using the `serialEvent()` event, your `loop` looks cleaner. That's always nice.

Comment: Yup, it was sending 3 messages for every RPI message. Thanks!